# How to reference a setup() variable in an imported function?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a component in which I define a reactive variable, and I would like to use it in an imported function. A simple example of the code is [available in the playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbmltcG9ydCB7IGNoYW5nZSB9ICBmcm9tICcuL2xpYi5qcydcbmltcG9ydCB7IHJlZiB9IGZyb20gJ3Z1ZSdcblxuY29uc3QgbXNnID0gcmVmKCdvbmUnKVxuY2hhbmdlKClcbjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuXG48dGVtcGxhdGU+XG4gIDxoMT57eyBtc2cgfX08L2gxPlxuPC90ZW1wbGF0ZT4iLCJpbXBvcnQtbWFwLmpzb24iOiJ7XG4gIFwiaW1wb3J0c1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJ2dWVcIjogXCJodHRwczovL3NmYy52dWVqcy5vcmcvdnVlLnJ1bnRpbWUuZXNtLWJyb3dzZXIuanNcIlxuICB9XG59IiwibGliLmpzIjoiZXhwb3J0IGNoYW5nZSA9ICgpID0+IG1zZy52YWx1ZSA9ICd0d28nIn0=)

`App.vue`

```html
<script setup>
import { change }  from './lib.js'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('one')
change()
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
</template>
```

`lib.js`

```js
export const change = () => msg.value = 'two'
```

The code above of course **does not work** because `change()` does not know `msg`. `Msg` on the other hand is not exportable as a `<setup script>` only variable.

My question: how should I declare `msg` so that I can refer to it from that exported function? Or, alternatively, is it possible to declare a reactive variable in `lib.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the `msg` as a param to your `change` method like this

`lib.js`

```js
export const change = (msg) => msg.value = 'two'
```

and use it like that in your file
`App.vue`

```js
const msg = ref('one')
change(msg)
```